# How to properly use environment variables in crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab, bashrc

I export a variable in my ~/.bashrc file (Ubuntu 20), which I'd like to use in a cron job.
Searching for answers, I found two ways of doing it, but none worked for me:

```
12 11 * * * BASH_ENV=/home/l86/.bashrc bash -l -c 'echo "USING TOKEN $GITTOKEN" >> /var/log/custom-cron.log 2>&1'
```

And also

```
12 11 * * * source /home/l86/.bashrc; echo "USING TOKEN $GITTOKEN" >> /var/log/custom-cron.log 2>&1
```

But the variable value is still being printed empty, which is not the case when I execute the same command outside cron (using the shell).

Comment: One command references `$TOKEN` and the other one `$GITTOKEN`, so one of them must be wrong.

Comment: @l0b0 sorry, that was my mistake while writing the question, but doesn't relate to the problem. I corrected the question, and crontab still doesn't see any variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your crontab is not executing the jobs in the BASH (/bin/bash), most likely in plain SH (/bin/sh) which should be pointing to DASH. So you need to follow this [solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301741/3022387) .. but with a couple of twists not explicitly mentioned there: the main one is .bashrc only runs *if the shell is interactive* ([reasons this is good](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257613/77959)). You should export the variable and may need to reference it with an escaped $-sign.
So in your source file:

```
export GITTOKEN="blah-123-secret-secret"
```

and then in your crontab you do

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'source /home/l86/.my-git-secret; echo "GIT: $GITTOKEN" >> /var/log/custom-cron.log 2>&1'
```

A possible solution to avoid redundancies - if you really need to keep your secret **only** in .bashrc - you could recapture it like so (do **NOT** have multiple occurrences of the string GITTOKEN in that file!):

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'export GITTOKEN="$(grep GITTOKEN /home/l86/.bashrc|cut -d= -f2)"; echo "GIT: $GITTOKEN" >> /var/log/custom-cron.log 2>&1'
```

To experiment with what the ENV(-ironment) looks like while running a cronjob you can run things like so:

```
env -i sh -c '/bin/bash -c "source /home/l86/.not-the-bashrc; echo \"SOURCED: $GITTOKEN, ${GITTOKEN}, \$GITTOKEN\""'
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I had no idea that .bashrc could only be used in interactive shell. So I created a separated file in my home folder to store my environment variables, which my jobs will also be able to use.

Comment: Well, no, there is nothing preventing you from _manually_ sourcing .bashrc in non-interactive shells (like in the original example) – the post on UnixSE only talks about bash _automatically_ sourcing bashrc for interactive shells only. Although many bashrc's do have an explicit "interactive || return" check inside, too... (and keep in mind that `source` itself is a bashism; `.` is how other shells spell it)

Comment: The OP mentions running on Ubuntu, so a few assumptions seemed reasonable shortcuts ;-)

Comment: @user1686 if that's the case, I don't know what was failing in my first attempts. Maybe changing _bash_ to _/bin/bash_ might have fixed it?

Comment: @Leandro-86 inspect the beginning of your bashrc, ubuntu has the bailout code user1686 spoke of; it may vary slightly from release to release but the "interactive || return" pseudocode is implemented. You should see it if you run "head ~/.bashrc".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `/bin/bash` shell right inside `crontab` in order to solve the conundrum:

(I am assuming you are dealing with your user crontab.)

`$ crontab -e`

Add this line at the top:

`SHELL=/bin/bash`

As for the command, you can now run a script or command in bash interactive mode with (example for your case -- please note the `-ic` switches, `i` is for "interactive" which allows to read your profile env vars):

`* * * * * bash -ic "(echo \"USING TOKEN $GITTOKEN\" >> /var/log/custom-cron.log 2>&1)"`

Save with `Ctrl+O`. Exit with `Ctrl+X`.

In case you have a bash script that uses your user environment variables, the cron line becomes something like this (my example runs every 15 minutes):

`*/15 9-15 * * 1-5 bash -ic "($HOME/.config/conky/scripts/stocks >> $HOME/.local/log/stocks.log 2>&1)" &`